# Mysqd service keeps dying

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos-7, wordpress

I'm running an AWS ec2 instance which is running a few WordPress sites.

Everything is fine except after a few hours my SQL service dies.  I have to reboot the whole machine to get it started.

I feel like its the RAM I'm running t3.nano which might have less ram.

Could i modify the setting to fix this issue or should i just get a bigger instance with more ram?  Thanks, guys

**Error log**

2019-05-15T17:50:35.149426Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-05-15T17:50:35.149923Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-05-15T17:50:35.645042Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-05-15T17:50:35.645973Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26) starting as process 12015 ...
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648459Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648480Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648483Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648494Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648497Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648658Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-05-15T17:50:35.648720Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649587Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649592Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649595Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649599Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649602Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649605Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649607Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-05-15T17:50:35.649637Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-05-15T17:50:35.649666Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-05-15T17:50:35.650172Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: There should be a log file that indicates the exact reason the service is crashing.

Comment: I found the file: